# Why $\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle$ is a distribution? $\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle$ defined inside.

Tags: distribution-theory

So I just started studying distribution theory and I am asked to show that $\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{-a} + \int_a^{\infty} \! \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-a}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a distribution for any $a>0$.

My book says that any function gives rise to a distribution by setting $\left\langle f,\varphi\right\rangle= \int_\Omega \! f(x)\varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and if this integral is defined. So I guess I should check the convergence of the integral above, but how to do this? I guess I still do not understand the concept of a distribution.

Comment: just check convergence of the integral + continuity in the sense of distributions. Because of the look of the thing around 0 you should get a first order distribution.

Comment: @mookid second order, because first derivative cancels out when you integrate $\int_{-a}^a \frac{x}{|x|}dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to estimate your  $|\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle|$ in terms of finite number of norms $\|\varphi\|_\infty$, $\|\varphi' \|_\infty$,..., $\|\varphi^{(k)}  \|_\infty$: more precisely, for every compact $K$ we need to find a constant $C_K$ and a number $n_K$ such that for any test function $\varphi$ with support in $K$ the following must hold:
$$\left|\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle\right|\le C_K\cdot (\|\varphi\|_\infty+\|\varphi' \|_\infty+\dots+\|\varphi^{(n_K)}  \|_\infty).$$

Let the compact be included in $[-R,R]$ and $R>a$.
We write
$$\left|\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle\right| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^{-a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x+ \int_a^{\infty} \! \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-a}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x\right|$$
$$\le \|\varphi\|_\infty\left(\int_{-R}^{-a} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}  + \int_{a}^{R} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}\right)+ \left|\int_{-a}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x\right|$$

The factor $\left(\int_{-R}^{-a} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}  + \int_{a}^{R} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}\right)$ does not depend on $\varphi$, so everything is ok.

Now to the second term, $ \int_{-a}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x $:$$
 \int_{-a}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x= \int_{0}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x-\int_{-a}^{0} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$ By Taylor it equals 
$$
\int_{0}^{a} \!  (\varphi' (0) +\varphi''(\xi_1)x/2 )  \mathrm{d}x-\int_{-a}^{0}    (\varphi' (0) +\varphi''(\xi_2)x/2 )    \mathrm{d}x $$ with $\xi_1\in(-a,0)$ and $\xi_2\in(0,a)$. Thus

$$\left|\int_{-a}^{a} \! \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|} \, \mathrm{d}x\right|\le \frac 12 \|\varphi''\|_\infty\int_{-a}^a|x|dx$$
Hence, by choosing $$C_K = \max \left(\left(\int_{-R}^{-a} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}  + \int_{a}^{R} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}\right),\frac 12  \int_{-a}^a|x|dx\right)$$ and $n_K=2$ we can conclude that indeed $f_a$ is a distribution.

The proof for the case $a\ge R$ is done likewise.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it seemed to be thorough. However, maybe I do lack some background, but I do not understand the very first statement that $\left\langle f_a,\varphi\right\rangle $ must be bounded by $C_K\left(\Vert\varphi\Vert_\infty + \Vert\varphi'\Vert_\infty + \cdots + \Vert\varphi^{(n_K)}\Vert_\infty\right)$. Why do you take the sum of the infinity norms of derivatives?

Comment: @IgnotasPetrulis this is merely a definition of distribution (at least in my course). If you give the definition that you use, we'll find the way to incorporate it in my answer.

Comment: Here is a link to the book I use [A Guide To Distribution Theory And Fourier Transforms](http://books.google.se/books?id=T7vEOGGDCh4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=lt&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). The exercise I posted is number $3$ on page $10$. The book simply states that $\left\langle f,\varphi\right\rangle=\int f(x)\varphi(x)$ is a distribution if the integral is absolutely convergent for every test function $\varphi$.

Comment: @IgnotasPetrulis It's a strange approach, because the author says that "we will define distributions as linear continuous functionals on $D(\Omega)$", then remarks "we will define continuous later", and then gives exercises on proving that something is a distribution. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) has a definition of distribution, but requires some knowledge in topology (especially, topology of multinorms). IF you can read French, then this book has a good introduction: [link](https://gargantua.polytechnique.fr/siatel-web/linkto/mICYYYS(JFY6).